# How to code a button in Squarespace to trigger the nav burger expanding on mobile

Tags: squarespace

I would like a button, either coded in a code block or some other way, when clicked to make the site act as if it's opening the nav burger on my mobile site. I am using Squarespace.

How would I do this?

click button --> navigation opens up in the same way as if I were to press it open.

I have yet to try anything other than try and search if anyone else has done this.